# Filemaker php api: encode for each loop variables to json

Tags: php, json, api, filemaker

I've been asked to provide filemaker data as json objects through the filemaker php api.

I've been able to use the following on a single record

```
 echo json_encode(array($namefamily, $namefirst, $dob, ));
```

Now I need to encode to json in my for each loop - not sure how to get it to work with concatenated variables in:

```
$records = $result->getRecords();
foreach($records as $record){
    echo' ' . $record->getField('NameFirst') . ' | ' . $record->getField('NameFamily') .' ';
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample content of $result?

Comment: the first example on a single record looks like 
    ["Joe" | "Blogs"]

for each loop simply returns 
    Joe Blogs Sam Smith Mary Jane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to previous answer, but using working FileMaker API syntax...

```
$records = $result->getRecords();

foreach($records as $record){
    $data[] = array( 
                    'NameFirst' => $record->getField("NameFirst"),
                    'NameFamily' => $record->getField("NameFamily")
                   );
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use array for its container hope it help..

```
$records = $result->getRecords();

$data = new Array()

foreach($records as $record){ 
$data.push({"firstname" -> $record->getField, "lastname" -> $record-> })
}
echo json_encode($data)
```